# How to return an average of last n rows from different group (indicated by a variable)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I've got a data like below:

```
data <- structure(list(seq = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L), new_seq = c(2, 2, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, NA, NA, 8, 8, 8, NA, NA, NA), value = c(2L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Column `new_seq` refers to the value of `seq`. For each value in `new_seq` which is not `NA` I would like to calculate a average of last `2` rows of `value` from respective `seq`. So, for example rows `1:2` of a new column should have a value of `0.5` (average of rows `49:50`), rows `51:54` also should have a value of `0.5` (average of rows `49:50` as well), but rows `60:63` should have value of `4` (average of rows `58:59`). How can I do that with `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
# calculate the mean value based on the last two rows of each seq
lookup <- data %>%
  group_by(seq) %>%
  mutate(rank = seq(n(), 1)) %>% 
  filter(rank <= 2) %>%
  summarise(new_column = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

# match back to original dataset (only non-NA values of new_seq can be matched)
left_join(data, lookup, by = c("new_seq" = "seq"))
```

Results in:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 4
     seq new_seq value new.column
   <int>   <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
 1     1       2     2        0.5
 2     1       2     0        0.5
 3     2      NA     0       NA  
 4     2      NA     1       NA  
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I need too make a little adjustment though, for those rows where `new_seq > seq` (rows `1:2` in the example) the mean should be calculated from not `2` last, but `2` first rows of referred `seq`. Can it be easily tweaked to cover this adjustment?

Comment: I've created another topic with details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382354/return-an-average-of-last-or-first-two-rows-from-a-different-group-indicated-by

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's only half `tidyverse` and I'm sure someone can do better, but here's an attempt.

`group_by` and `mutate` make it easy to calculate the average of the last 2 rows of the group, but I couldn't figure out how to get the connection between `seq` and `new_seq` so I did that in base R.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
    group_by(seq) %>%
    mutate(end_val = (nth(value, -1L) + nth(value, -2L))/2)

dat3$result <- apply(dat2, 1, function(x) {
    dat2[dat2$seq == x['new_seq'], 'end_val'][[1]][1]
})
```

Here's the result. I subsetted the relevant rows (since otherwise it'd be too long to see on the screen at once) but added the original row numbers as the `rowid` column:

```
dat3 %>% tibble::rowid_to_column() %>% .[c(1:3,50:55,59:64),] 

# A tibble: 15 x 6
# Groups:   seq [6]
   rowid   seq new_seq value end_val result
   <int> <int>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1       2     2     1      0.5
 2     2     1       2     0     1      0.5
 3     3     2      NA     0     0.5   NA  
 4    50     2      NA     1     0.5   NA  
 5    51     3       2     0     3.5    0.5
 6    52     3       2     0     3.5    0.5
 7    53     3       2     3     3.5    0.5
 8    54     3       2     4     3.5    0.5
 9    55     4      NA     5     4     NA  
10    59     4      NA     5     4     NA  
11    60     5       4     0     2      4  
12    61     5       4     1     2      4  
13    62     5       4     1     2      4  
14    63     5       4     3     2      4  
15    64     6      NA     2     2     NA
```